# Programming in Python; writing a Caesar Cipher using a zip() method

Tags: python

I have a homework problem: to encrypt a message using a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). I need to be able to have the user input a number to shift the encryption by. For example, shifting by 4 would change 'A' into 'E'. The user also needs to input the string to be translated. The book says to use the `zip()` function to solve the problem. I'm not sure how that would work.

I have this (but it doesn't do anything):

```
def caesarCipher(string, shift):
    strings = ['abc', 'def']
    shifts = [2,3]
    for string, shift in zip(strings, shifts):
        # do something?

print caesarCipher('hello world', 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for tagging as homework! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287686/caesar-cipher-program-using-zip-in-python

Comment: Alright; what do you expect your code to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to build a lookup table (dictionary), and use the dictionary to encipher your text.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def cipher(plaintext, shift):
   # Build a lookup table between the alphabet and the shifted alphabet.
   table = dict(zip(alphabet, alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[0:shift]))
   # Convert each character to its shifted equivalent. 
   # N.B. This doesn't handle non-alphabetic characters
   return ''.join(table[c] for c in plaintext.lower())
```

Answer (score 3):

"zip" is a builtin function of Python, not a certain type of method as your question title implies.

```
>>> help(zip)
Help on built-in function zip in module __builtin__:

zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

>>>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a well-formed comment

Comment: I don't seem to be able to comment on the question itself. I guess I need some more points?

Comment: Oh, maybe. I shall upvote your answer then!

Comment: I also upvoted your other answer :P